# Microsoft Data Platform Competency Spatial Data Types Failing

Tags: sql-server, spatial, geography

I am attempting to pass the The SQL Server 2012 Platform Ready Tests.

I have selected "Spatial Data" as one of the tests. My SQL database contains a geography data type field. I have an app that is inserting multiple records into this table, and then reading them back out (including DBGeography records).

When I run the Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool V4.1 and go through the steps, it fails the Spatial test stating:
No records for geography data type were found or the records count found is less than 2.

Test Status: Fail
Test case/Verification: TC 11.1 - Is geography data type present and is the record count greater than 1 for the given table in the SQL instance?

As I have Geography field, and it is populated with multiple records, I do not understand why this is failing.
create table blah 
{ field1..., 
[IncidentLocation] [geography] NOT NULL,
}

Any suggestions as to how to get it to pass?

Comment: I contacted the Microsoft Platform Ready team for help on this. Instead of an answer, they decided to give a waiver for the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve issues where you believe the test should be passing, contact the MPR support providing your application id.
Odds are they will grant you a waiver passing the test for you.